# how to ajax for chatting website without page reload

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

want to create a fully dynamic chat UI for my website, But it reloads the whole page if a person submits the button page should not reload like many chat website.

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" id="formpost">
<input type="text" id="input" value="php echo">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

I want to submit this form through ajax and show the last xml `<message>` containing `<message>talk 123<message>`

```
<messages category="short">
<person1>
<time>
r
<message>Djssjs</message>
</time>
</person1>
<person2>
<time>
r
<message>1234fdg</message>
</time>
</person2>
<person1>
<time>
 r
<message> talk 123</message>
</time>
</person1>
</messages>
```

i want to show that talk 123 in the html document bit confused how to do that

```
 //for form submit 
 $("#formpost").submit(function(e) {

 var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: action.php,
           data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});

//for xml 

function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  myFunction(this);
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "name.xml", true);
xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
var msg = "";

//how to select the last person's of the <messages> child

msg = getElementsByTagName("messages").lastChild.childNodes[1].nodeValue ; 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = msg;
}
```

Comment: Try putting `e.preventDefault()` immediately inside `.submit()` instead of being the last instruction to execute in there

Comment: If you really want realtime chatting, you'd use websockets or other tech faster than ajax. And what you describe is standard behavour for a submit button. Don't use a submit button ( use a different type button ) or `preventDefault()` the submit event. Also, JSON will be more efficient than XML due to JSON parsing faster.

Comment: Also, as a sidenote, PHP and XML really feel like technologies from the '90s if you want to make a chat. To go realtime, now we have websockets carrying JSON and all. (Edit : high five @Shilly)

Comment: yeah but thanks but whats the prroblem here im facing

Comment: guys is my code all correct ? @JeremyThille

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#formpost").on('submit', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();

  // rest of your ajax code here...  
});
```

**Points to note**
1. Make sure you have also added JQuery script source on the head tag of your chat page.
 2. Make sure to put preventDefault() immediately before any other code is executed.

Comment: prevent default can you tell me more about this, is there any mistake i ve done in my code

Comment: @Anjali This answer looks pretty clear and explicit to me, and I had also said this in the comments. "is there any mistake i ve done in my code", we've addressed that multiple times already, as well as advices about technology choices.

Comment: @JeremyThille `msg = getElementsByTagName("messages").lastChild.childNodes[1].nodeValue ; 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = msg;` i dont know whether this is working or not ,instead of phph im using ajax

Comment: `Instead of PHP I'm using Ajax`, yes you _are_ using PHP, and PHP and Ajax have nothing to do with each other. Really, IMO you should learn the basics before attempting something as tough as a real time chat.

Comment: btw side note @JeremyThille didnt work still struggling

Answer (score -1):

You can use reverse ajax method pulling data from the server.

In reverse ajax a request is auto-generated at a certain time interval or hold the request for fetching new message.

There are three technologies for reverse ajax:-

1. Piggyback
2. Polling
3. Comet